# Golang XML Unmarshalling Elements vs Attributes

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have the following sample XML snippet and am running in to an issue where I can't find a way to extract both the values and attributes of a specific item.

Sample XML:

```xml
<item version="2">
    <m compressor="snappy" seekable="N">
        <b k="block_sentinel">2vFJNBXc6Sk8EoeYeRBIuQ==</b>
        <b k="tail_sentinel">v6E/qStZR/CXKBVmVT2q4w==</b>
    </m>
</item>
```

It seems as if with Golangs "encoding/xml" package I can either extract the Values (2vFJNBXc6Sk8EoeYeRBIuQ==, v6E/qStZR/CXKBVmVT2q4w==) or the Attributes (k="block_sentinel, k="tail_sentinel), but not both at the same time.

Here is a test code with [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/5PS74CKeXFE) and the code below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

// sample xml
var sample = []byte(`
    <item version="2">
        <m compressor="snappy" seekable="N">
            <b k="block_sentinel">2vFJNBXc6Sk8EoeYeRBIuQ==</b>
            <b k="tail_sentinel">v6E/qStZR/CXKBVmVT2q4w==</b>
        </m>
    </item>
`)

// exml1 struct gives me all of the b attributes, but none of the values of b.
type exml1 struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"item"`
    Version xml.Attr `xml:"version,attr,omitempty"`
    M       struct {
        XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"m"`
        Compressor xml.Attr `xml:"compressor,attr,omitempty"`
        Seekable   xml.Attr `xml:"seekable,attr,omitempty"`
        B          []struct {
            XMLName xml.Name `xml:"b"`
            K       xml.Attr `xml:"k,attr,omitempty"`
        } `xml:"b"`
    } `xml:"m"`
}

// exml2 struct gives me all of the values, but none of the attributes of b
type exml2 struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"item"`
    Version xml.Attr `xml:"version,attr,omitempty"`
    M       struct {
        XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"m"`
        Compressor xml.Attr `xml:"compressor,attr,omitempty"`
        Seekable   xml.Attr `xml:"seekable,attr,omitempty"`
        B          []string `xml:"b"`
    } `xml:"m"`
}

func main() {
    var x1 exml1
    var x2 exml2

    if err := xml.Unmarshal(sample, &x1); err != nil {
        log.Panicf("xml > %v :: err > %s", x1, err)
    }
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(sample, &x2); err != nil {
        log.Panicf("xml > %v :: err > %s", x2, err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", x1)
    // {{ item} {{ version} 2} {{ m} {{ compressor} snappy} {{ seekable} N} [{{ b} {{ k} block_sentinel}} {{ b} {{ k} tail_sentinel}}]}}
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", x2)
    // {{ item} {{ version} 2} {{ m} {{ compressor} snappy} {{ seekable} N} [2vFJNBXc6Sk8EoeYeRBIuQ== v6E/qStZR/CXKBVmVT2q4w==]}}

    // What I would like to end up with:
    // {{ item} {{ version} 2} {{ m} {{ compressor} snappy} {{ seekable} N} [{{ b} 2vFJNBXc6Sk8EoeYeRBIuQ== {{ k} block_sentinel}} {{ b} v6E/qStZR/CXKBVmVT2q4w== {{ k} tail_sentinel}}]}}
}
```

I am trying to extract all of the data out of the sample XML, but am failing to do so, couldn't find anyone with similar issues online so thought I'd ask StackOverflow.

Comment: Fix `exml1.M.B` slice's element type to include a field of type `string` with tag option `,innerxml`. From the docs: *"If the struct has a field of type []byte or string with tag ",innerxml", Unmarshal accumulates the raw XML __nested inside the element__ in that field. The rest of the rules still apply."*

Comment: Thank you! Got it to work! [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RkHy033eq8U)